# jQuery : jqPrint outputs a <div> as scrollable

Tags: jquery, jqprint

I tried to print a div using jqPrint. All the contents that are printed are fine but scroll bar appears in all pages of printed sheets.

Is there any CSS corrections or references needs to be given/added?

Please do help

Comment: need to change css using jquery

Comment: I am using version 0.3 and unable to find the documentation in jQuery plugin site as it is currently under maintenance.

Wats the latest version ? and where can I get it ..? Thanks for ur help

Comment: On Github.com    https://github.com/tanathos/jquery.jqprint

Comment: You have already latest one

Comment: How about adding an additional CSS stylesheet with `media="print"`, adding overflow: visible and display: block to all DIV layers?

Answer (score 1):

Try this One Example 
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/v6K58/)
Here you can print without scroll

```
$(function() {
    $( "#printMe" ).click(function() {
        $('#header').jqprint();

    });
});​
```

Comment: I have used another plugin from here http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm ; 
This works wonderfully!

Comment: JQ Print works for small amount of data. I have a table with 450 rows, printing such one given a hiccup!